# Is 'Sanjeevani Booti' known to be present in current times as well?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, lakshmana

We have read about the use of *Sanjeevani Booti* in Ramayana, which was used to cure Lakshmana and the Vanara army when they were unconscious and on death bed. I want to know what particular type of illness it could cure and is there any account of its existence in current time.

I think I read a newspaper article in *Rashtriya Sahara* newspaper, Delhi around 10-15 years ago stating that there is supposed to be a similar herb found in the same regions (I think in China) called Ching-wa.

The person who found that was told to have tried it on his dead father. He took out the corpse of his father from graveyard and put the body in water treated with Ching-wa and after sometime his father came back to life but it was said that he didn't remember anything and was behaving abnormally.

The newspaper compared it with 'Sanjeevani' herb. Do we know of any such thing present in current time?

Comment: Sanjeevani is not a single herb. Hanuman was asked to bring four herbs. For the details of the illness it could cure, see [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) answer of mine.

Comment: @SreeCharan Thanks for you comment but can you please give the correct link of your answer. The current link is for stackexchange chatroom

Comment: Oh! some mess up.  Take a look at it [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16660/why-did-lord-hanuman-bring-two-mountains-from-himalayas/18801#18801). It's working now.

Comment: @SreeCharan, thanks for the correct link. Its good to know that Lord Hanuman brought the mountain twice and not once as known by most people.