# Who prescribed sanjivani when Lakshmana became unconscious?

Tags: ramayana, rama, lakshmana

This is a question about Ramayana. In the battle between Rama and Ravana, Lakshmana was struck with an arrow shot by Meghnad, the son of Ravana. Lakshmana became unconscious. Which healer was then called by Rama ?

Answer (score 3):

**Sushena, a monkey physician** tested Lakshmana when he was hit by a shakti by Ravana [(not Meghanad](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2348/5212). It is according to Ramcharitmanas, Lakshmana was hit by Mefhnad).

When Sri Rama was worried and heart broken that Lakshmana was hit by Ravana, he laments and gets ready to die like his brother (Sri Rama thought Lakshmana died). Then Sushena, the physician of Vanaras said these comfortable words to Rama.

From Yuddha Kanda [Sarga 101](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga101/yuddha_101_frame.htm) of Valmiki Ramayana,

> राममेवं ब्रुवाणं तु शोकव्याकुलितेन्द्रियम् || ६-१०१-२४
>   आश्वासयन्नुवाचेदं **सुषेणः** परमं वचः |
>
> Comforting Rama, whose mind was full of grief and who was thus lamenting, **Sushena, for his part**, addressed the following excellent words:
>
> नैव पञ्चत्वमापन्नो लक्ष्मणो लक्ष्मिवर्धनः || ६-१०१-२६
>   न ह्य्स्य विकृतं वक्त्रं न च श्यामत्वमागतम् |
>
> "Lakshmana, the augmenter of prosperity, has not got into death. His countenance is not changed, nor has it become dark."
>
> His face may be seen with a good brightness and very much placid. The palms of his hands are resembling the petals of a lotus. His eyes too are very bright."

He is the one who prescribed the life bringing herbs and asked Hanuman to bring them quickly. He gives different herbs names for different purposes. But Hanuman could not identify those precious herbs. So, he uprooted the whole Oushadhi mountain and restored it back to its original position after the mission is over.

[Hanuman brought the mountain twice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18801/5212). He also brought them once to bring back the lives of dead and wounded Vanaras. The first instance is when the most of the Vanaras including Rama and Lakshmana fell unconscious due to the effect of Brahmastra shot by Indrajeet. Then Jambavan prescribes it and asks Hanuman to bring the herbs because the physician Suṣeṇa was also unconscious. This is said in [Sarga 74](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddha_74_frame.htm) of Valmiki Ramayana.

So, for the first time when whole army fell down, it was Jambavan who prescribed. **When Lakshmana alone fell unconscious, it was Sushena, the physician**.

---

According to Ramcharitmanas, a fierce battle took place between Lakshmana and Indrajit. Indrajit throws a javelin into the chest of Lakshmana. He was wounded severely and fell unconscious. Jambavan says to bring Sushena and Sushena prescribes Sanjivani.

> Jåmbavån  said, Suṣeṇa,  the  physician,  lives  in  Lankå;  someone  should  be sent  to  fetch  him  here. Assuming  a  minute  (indiscernible)  form  Hanumån  went  and immediately  brought  him,  house  and  all. Doha 54 Chaupai 4
>
> rāmapadārabinda sira nāyau āyi suśena |
>    kahānāmagiri auṣadhī  jāhu pavānāsuta lenā
>
> **Suṣeṇa  came  and  bowed  his  head  at Lord  Råma's  lotus-feet.  He  mentioned  the name of the herb as well as of the mountain where it could be had**, and said, "Proceed, O  son  of  the  wind-god,  to  bring  it. Doha 55

So, It is Sushena in Ramcharitmanas also. But he is not said as Vanara.

Answer (score 0):

Sanjeevani was prescribed by Jambavan, see the [reference](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddha_74_frame.htm) below about the conversation between Jambavan and Hanuman:

> Thereafter, that Jambavan of great splendour spoke to Hanuma as
>   follows: "Come on, O foremost of monkeys! You ought to protect the
>   lives of monkeys."
>
> "O Hanuma! You ought to go to Himalaya, the foremost of mountains, by
>   traveling higher and higher over the large ocean."
>
> "O annihilator of enemies! Thereafter, you will see there the Mount
>   Rishabha, the excellent mountain and the very much powerful peak of
>   Kailasa, with a golden hue."
>
> "O foremost of monkeys! Sprouted on the head of that mountain, are
>   four blazing herbs. You can see them, illuminating the ten quarters."
>
> "You can see there, Mrita Sanjivani (capable of restoring the dead to
>   life), Vishalyakarani (capable of extracting weapons and healing all
>   wounds inflicted by weapons), Suvarnakarani (restoring the body to its
>   original complexion) and Sandhani, the great herb (capable of joining
>   severed limbs or fractured bone)."

Comment: This is the first time. Lakshmana was hit by Ravana and it is second time. This time it is Sushena not jambavan

Comment: I agree but when you know what to get and from where to get, next time something happens anyone can recall what was done in the first case, hence credit should be given to the first person. This is what I feel.

Comment: The question is asking for the second time not the first time. No, it is Sushena for the second time. Even for the second time, Hanuman didn't know where the herbs are. So, he brought the total mountain.